# Facebook Login on iPhone causes "lang: error: linker command failed"

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The following is my UIViewController for requesting Facebook login and publish_actions permission. When I run my project, I get a `lang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`, which I also include below. Thanks for any help

**UIViewController**

```
#import "FacebookViewController.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface FacebookViewController ()<FBLoginViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation FacebookViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];

    loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
#ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_7_0
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
        loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
    }
#endif
#endif
#endif
    loginview.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:loginview];

    [loginview sizeToFit];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - FBLoginViewDelegate

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    // ask for more permission
    if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
        // if we don't already have the permission, then we request it now
        [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                              defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                if (!error) {
                                                    //No error therefore dismiss this VC
                                                    [self dismissThisViewController];

                                                } else if (error.fberrorCategory != FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
                                                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Permission denied"
                                                                                                        message:@"Unable to get permission to post"
                                                                                                       delegate:nil
                                                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                    [alertView show];
                                                }
                                            }];
    }
}

- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error {
    // see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/ for general guidance on error handling for Facebook API
    // our policy here is to let the login view handle errors, but to log the results
    NSLog(@"FBLoginView encountered an error=%@", error);
}


-(void)dismissThisViewController
{
    //TODO
}

@end
```

**ERROR**

```
Ld /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-
dbqrudioiirqmvckhvljpnmkbhlu/Build/Intermediates/Appname.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/Appname.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Appname normal x86_64
    cd /my_git_dir/project_name/Appname_iOS
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -
L/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-dbqrudioiirqmvckhvljpnmkbhlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -
F/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-dbqrudioiirqmvckhvljpnmkbhlu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/my_git_dir/project_name/Appname_iOS/Appname_iOS -
F/Users/myname/Documents/FacebookSDK -filelist /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-
dbqrudioiirqmvckhvljpnmkbhlu/Build/Intermediates/Appname.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Appname.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Appname.LinkFileList -
Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -
no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework AVFoundation -framework StoreKit -framework QuartzCore -framework
 AudioToolbox -lsqlite3 -framework FacebookSDK -lz -framework CoreLocation -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework 
MobileCoreServices -framework CFNetwork -framework Bolts -framework CoreTelephony -framework Parse -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -
framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-
dbqrudioiirqmvckhvljpnmkbhlu/Build/Intermediates/Appname.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Appname.build/Objects-
normal/x86_64/Appname_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Appname-
dbqrudioiirqmvckhvljpnmkbhlu/Build/Intermediates/Appname.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Appname.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Appname

…

duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFMeasurementEvent in:
    /Users/myname/Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
    /my_git_dir/project_name/Appname_iOS/Appname_iOS/Bolts.framework/Bolts(BFMeasurementEvent.o)
ld: 91 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


ld: 91 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicate meethod name BFMeasurementElement in Bolts and also Facebook framework. Solve this first. Bolts framework<- do you realy need this?

Comment: I have no idea what Bolts is used for. I take it out and it now works. Until I find some reason why I need Bolts, this is the correct answer. Thanks!